# Rails 3, make exception links clickable and open in editor (textmate)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textmate, textmatebundles

I have a Rails 3 installation running on a remote development server. Is it possible to make the exception lines clickable and open in an editor like textmate on my local maschine? I would save a lot of time if I did not have to manually open textmate, find file and line number.

NoMethodError in Arts#index

Showing **/home/demo1/app/widgets/art_widgets/list/display.html.erb** where line #9 raised:

Best regards.
Asbjørn Morell

Comment: I think this might help you, although I'm not sure how to edit the rails error page to actually insert this: http://blog.macromates.com/2007/the-textmate-url-scheme/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found a great plugin that does exactly this! [rails-stacktrace-textmate-linker-greasemonkey-script](https://github.com/ryankshaw/rails-stacktrace-textmate-linker-greasemonkey-script)

1. Install greasemonkey from here: http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748
2. Install rails-stacktrace-textmate-linker by clicking the link in the install section: https://github.com/ryankshaw/rails-stacktrace-textmate-linker-greasemonkey-script This will load the greasemonkey-script.
3. Go to Add-ons -> User Scripts -> Right click the Rails Stacktrace Linker and click edit.
4. Edit line 37 and 49. You will need to add the path to your rails Application.

   ... href='txmt://open?url=file:///Users/atmorell/Dropbox/MorellusWallace/", ...

Reload your application in firefox and enjoy nice clickable stacktrace that opens in textmate :)

WINNING!

Answer (score 0):

Not in a simple way.

You'd need a software running in the background that would interpret the exception page to put links in it, and then open the software, file and find the line specified. As far as I know, there's no first-party solution.

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted textmate link(txmt://) in Rails Error Page. But until now no success.

[rails-footnotes](https://github.com/josevalim/rails-footnotes) has similar feature. It insert txmt link to every page. But not in Error page.

[someone on rails-talk mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-talk/browse_thread/thread/fb04f234e1679d69/a6c5c673de67292b?lnk=gst&q=textmate%20trace#a6c5c673de67292b) asked same question. and said merb had that feature.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the rails footnotes gem will give you clickable file references in your application trace.

https://github.com/josevalim/rails-footnotes

I found this gem slowed my dev environment down a little so disabled it's main functionality, I only needed it purely for the clickable file references. You can do this by adding the following line in the .rails_footnotes file in the root of your app.

```
Footnotes::Filter.notes = []
```